What exactly means "Idi adsum"
In a quest to finding myself, I would like a latin tattoo with the symbol X and the writing "Idi adsum". Because it's permanent, and because I don't want to endup with something that doesn't make sense. Can someone validate the best expression for an equivalent to "I'm here for now"?
(In French: Maintenant je suis ici)

I'm pretty sure "for now" adds something beyond French "maintenant." The implication of the English phrase is that it's just temporary.

Just to be clear:
No, what you propose is not valid Latin.
If you switch "idi" to "ibi" it becomes grammatical but doesn't make much sense and doesn't mean what you want.
You are much better off taking a Latin text based on something different.
You have one suggestion in a good answer now, and there may be more later.
